# strange behaviour in my code using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This might sound silly, but I'm trying to understand my own code and I wanted to see your input here. I'm using useRef() to click a HTML element on user changing the screen. For some reason the ref.current passes the if condition I created so it only executes if this isn't null. Not sure why? I managed to make it work but I had to add an additional if statement to the onresize function, could someone explain why this is the case.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import classes from './Backdrop.css';

const backdrop = (props) => {
    const backDropRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {

        if (backDropRef.current !== null && props.show) {
            document.body.onresize = () => {
                if (backDropRef.current !== null) {
                    backDropRef.current.click();
                }
            };
        }
    }, [backDropRef.current, props.show]);

    let classForBackdrop = classes.Backdrop;

    if (props.toolTipShow) {
        classForBackdrop = classes.BackdropForToolTip;
    }

    return props.show ? (
        <div
            ref={backDropRef}
            className={classForBackdrop}
            onClick={props.clicked}
            id="back-drop"
        ></div>
    ) : null;
};

export default backdrop;
```

Comment: are you asking why `current` is `null` ever?

Comment: No no, why do I need the if statement inside the onresize arrow function? I was under the impression that the first if atatement will not allow to get to that point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will break into parts:

- on true at if conditional it attaches `onresize` listener that has `backDropRef.current.click()`;
- `backDropRef.current` points to your `div`;
- once `show` prop turns to false `div` is removed from DOM;
- `backDropRef.current` lost `div` reference, and now is `null`;

After all this, you need the if condition because otherwise any `resize` event triggered when `show` is false there is no `<div>`, `backDropRef.current` is `null` and you try to call `click` on a `null` value which throws an error.